# ASP.NET Click Event Handle - How to pass an argument in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, events

I'm using the accordion Ajax control. For each Accordion pane I have text and a Button dynamically created. When the user fires the click event I want to know what button in which pane was fired. So I want to handle the button's click event in a way that I can send the ID (probably by event args) to the event handler in order for the handler to know what to do according to the button that was pressed.

I know I have to do something like this:

```
AddHandler bGetSessionMembers.Click, AddressOf bGetSessionMembers_click
```

but I whanted to do something like this:

```
AddHandler bGetSessionMembers.Click, AddressOf bGetSessionMembers_click(Me, "My ID")
```

I think you can do that in C#

```
bGetSessionMembers.Click += bGetSessionMembers_click(Me, "My ID")
```

or even in C# but with anonimous delegates.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better way to do this.  First, wire up your buttons like normal:

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Click
AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf Click
```

Then create a `Click` method like this:

```
Sub click(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = TryCast(o, Button)    
    If button IsNot Nothing Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Inside that if statement you now have a `Button` - you can grab its `ID` or anything else about it that you'd like.

**Edit in response to comment:**

I think you may be misunderstanding how events are wired up in .NET.  When you do this:

```
AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf Click
```

You are not calling the method `Click`, you are passing a delegate to a compiler-generated method for the `Button.Click` event that adds your delegate to a delegate invocation list.  When the `Button` raises its `Click` event your delegate is invoked by the `Button`.

Since you will not be the one to invoke the method via the delegate you cannot change what gets passed in.  Your best option is to use the `Object` that is passed to you and cast it to a `Button` like I did above.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is superb, and exactly what I'd do. I'd just like to add to the code snippet he wrote, because that blank line looks like it is crying out for a snippet showing how to use the CommandArgument and CommandName properties of System.Web.UI.Button:

```
Sub click(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = TryCast(o, Button)    
    If button IsNot Nothing Then
        Select Case button.CommandName
          Case "Command1"
            'Your cool feature here :)
          Case "Command2"
            'You could check button.CommandArgument to get additional data
          Case Else
            'Runs if button.CommandName isn't handled by your code
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Andy - hope you don't mind me throwing some more stuff in here :)

HTH,

Richard.